Generic USB pendrive is corrupted. how to recover?
I had formatted my USB pen drive after installing the OS, but now it's showing volume has No media. How to recover my pen drive to normal mode?


You've provided no clues as to what you're running, nor what you actually want. When an ISO is burnt (written, etc) to a thumb-drive correctly; all prior formatting and partition tables are erased & replaced with the details taken from the ISO itself (unless reformatting was done during write of ISO - whomever wrote the ISO will know method used to write ISO)..   If you want to use the thumb-drive for other purposes; just create a new partition table on the device; then you can format it...  Try using the GEARS icon in your picture.
